# Miracast not working? TV supports, PC supports and sees TV as device, just can't project

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, tv, miracast, smart-tv

I'm trying to mirror my desktop's screen on my TV, the setup is the following:

Windows 10 Pro Desktop connected to router via gigabit.
LG Smart TV connected to the same router on wifi.ac

dxdiag confirmed Pc is Miracast capable - TV is miracast capable, works fine from my android phone.

In devices i can add the TV (actually i don't even need to as it automatically shows up as two devices one as a media cast destination the other as a miracast)
[devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHdtH.png)

I can cast from Films & TV just fine.

If i try windows + P the project screen comes up, just nothing happens if i click on any of the options (duplicate, extend or 2nd only).

All drives and TV refreshed to latest.

What am i doing wrong here?

---

**Turns DX diag reported (probably) the capability because i had once had a wifi card in my PC. Reinstalling the card made things work.**

**Also you should test the capability by `Windows` + `K` and not by  `Windows` + `P` ! If you are capable to connect to wireless displays this will surefire tell you.**

**Films and TV: i dug into the topic and turns out in this case win 10 has a built in DLNA server to serve these requests, so it's not using miracast just plain old service discovery and push.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, you need to select “Connect to a wireless display”. Which you can’t because you probably don’t have a wireless card.

Normal Miracast works over Wi-Fi Direct, a point-to-point link between the device and the display (or Miracast receiver). It does not use your regular network or your regular wireless network.

Microsoft also offers *Miracast over Infrastructure*, which uses the existing network to host the Miracast connection. However, it is *very* unlikely your TV supports this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you are absolutely right, turns out what happened is that i had a wifi card a long time ago in my PC, so probably that's why WIN 10 reported capability.